# How to add space two divs?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

Between the last two cards and the image at the bottom I need some more space, but the space has to increase as I reduce the size of the browser window. How do I do this?
The first image shows the browser in full screen.
The second image shows a smaller browser window (just a little smaller)

[image: This is the how it looks with a full screen browser]

---

[image: This is how it looks when I reduce the browser in size a little bit]

This is my html code:

```
 <section>
 <!--....Some other things....-->

<div class="container" id ="last-row-cards">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 margin">
                  <div class="speaker">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn">
                                <img src="" alt="user-image" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-modal"></div>

                        <div class="card-info">

                            <div class="name">
                                <p style="font-size: 28px;font-weight: 100;font-family: 'Raleway';" class="name">Nunc Lorem Interdum</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="social-network">
                                <a href="#" class="icon youtube">
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="icon twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="icon facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <hr>

                            <div class="content" style="font-family: raleway;">
                                <p style="font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: 'Raleway';">
                                    <b>About:</b> Praesent faucibus sem tortor, sed imperdiet enim interdum in. Etiam feugiat rutrum ex, quis maximus quam commodo eu. Pellentesque eget tortor convallis, vestibulum tortor in, lacinia diam.
                                </p>
                                <p style="font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: 'Raleway';"><b>Website:</b> <a href="http://something.io/" style="color:grey">www.something.io</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

              </div>

                <div class="col-md-6 margin">
                  <div class = "speaker2">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <a href="#" type="button" class="btn">
                                <img src="" alt="user-image" />
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-modal"></div>

                        <div class="card-info">

                            <div class="name">
                                <p style="font-size: 28px;font-weight: 100;font-family: 'Raleway';" class="name">Nunc Lorem Interdum</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="social-network">
                                <a href="#" class="icon youtube">
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="icon twitter">
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                </a>
                                <a href="#" class="icon facebook">
                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <hr>

                            <div class="content" style="font-family: raleway;">
                                <p style="font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: 'Raleway';">
                                    <b>About:</b> Praesent faucibus sem tortor, sed imperdiet enim interdum in. Etiam feugiat rutrum ex, quis maximus quam commodo eu. Pellentesque eget tortor convallis, vestibulum tortor in, lacinia diam.
                                </p>
                                <p style="font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: 'Raleway';"><b>Website:</b> <a href="http://something.io/" style="color:grey">www.something.io</a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
     </section>
     <section class="create">
    <div class="innov8">
        <h4>Create</h4>
    </div>
</section>
```

My CSS code

```
.create {
background-image: url('http://www.davidduke.com/images/Mad-Scientists.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;
margin-top: 50% !important;
margin-bottom:0;
}

/* General */
.row {
box-sizing: border-box;
outline: none;
width: 100%;
}
/* Card */
.card {
background-image: url('');
background-size: 100%;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-       stop(0%, #ffffff), color-stop(100%, #ecf0f1));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ecf0f1 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #ecf0f1  100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%, #ecf0f1 100%);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
display: block;
position: absolute;
padding: 20px;
}

.card-modal {
-moz-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
-o-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.19, 1, 0.22, 1);
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #bdc3c7;
color: white;
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 130px;
z-index: 2;
padding: 20px;
}

#last-row-cards{
 /*I'M NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE*/
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your first section is not position:relative 
you can remove your postiion:relative on .create class ..
so it can go down.. 
but if you use float of one of your elements inside your section, you need to clear it so it will properly make a block .. 
ex:

```
<div class="first">
</div>
<div class="second">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
css
.first {
float: left;
}
.second {
float: right;
}
.clear{
clear: both;
}
```

- bootstrap col-md, col-sm, col-lg use float .. so you must clear it at the end ..

Comment: I've added more CSS code. Can you please check it out? Nothing is working.

Comment: Ok, so now my code is working but I'm still manually doing it. At that width it doesn't overlap but when I make it smaller it begins to overlap again.

Comment: how about you make your width using vh .. like width: 50vh .. 
vh automatically resize depends on the size of the screen based on height.. 
you can use vw for the size of the screen based on width ..